# android fontFamily fallback font for missing glyphs

Tags: android, fonts, android-support-library, font-face, font-family

When using new Custom Font on Android with Android Support Library, I'm getting a display issue on Android 4.1 (API 16) while it works OK on 8.0 (API 26):

[image: API 16, NOK]
[image: API 26, OK]

Here is `activity_main.xml` content, using custom font AvenirNext Medium (stored in `res/font/avenirnext_medium.ttf`):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenirnext_medium"
            android:text="Hello world?"/> <!-- this is an unbreakable space -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm targeting SDK 26 while supporting down to SDK 16.

**What can I do to get rid of the replacement character '�' in API 16?**

Comment: set the text programmatically  and  check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HermantParmar comment, it looks like special characters like unbreakable spaces must appears via unicode value (`\u00A0`). So I modified `text` attribute and it's now working fine:

```
android:text="Hello\u00A0world?"/>
```